# Python Recurisve Backtracking to create a maze

Tags: python, recursive-backtracking

I'm trying to create a maze through recursive backtracking but I can't seem to call create_maze() properly. From my main menu I call the maze class like this

maze = Maze.create_maze(NoOfRows, NoOfColumns)

However, I get an argument error from create_maze saying I'm missing an additional "y" or my self.path(0 is missing an additional y

Where am I going wrong?

```
from numpy.random import random_integers as rand
from Generate import ascii_representation
from constants import *
import numpy as np

WALL_TYPE = np.int8
WALL = 0
EMPTY = 1
RED = 2
BLUE = 3


class Maze:
    def __init__(self, Width, Height):
        self.Width = Width
        self.Height = Height
        self.board = np.zeros((Width, Height), dtype=WALL_TYPE)
        self.board.fill(EMPTY)

    def set_borders(self):
        self.board[0, :] = self.board[-1, :] = WALL
        self.board[:, 0] = self.board[:, -1] = WALL

    def is_wall(self, x, y):
        return self.board[x][y] == WALL

    def set_wall(self, x, y):
        self.board[x][y] = WALL

    def remove_wall(self, x, y):
        self.board[x][y] = EMPTY

    def in_maze(self, x, y):
        return 0 <= x < self.Width and 0 <= y < self.Height

    def write_to_file(self, filename):
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.write(ascii_representation(self))
        f.close()

    def set_path(self, x, y):
       self.board[y][x] = False

    @staticmethod
    def load_from_file(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            content = f.readlines()

        # remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
        content = [x.strip() for x in content]

        xss = []
        for line in content:
            xs = []

            for c in line:
                if c == ' ':
                    xs.append(EMPTY)
                elif c == 'X':
                    xs.append(WALL)
                else:
                    raise ValueError('unexpected character found: ' + c)

            xss.append(xs)

        maze = Maze(len(xss), len(xss[0]))

        for xs in xss:
            assert len(xs) == maze.Height

        for i in range(maze.Width):
            for j in range(maze.Height):
                if xss[i][j] == EMPTY:
                    maze.remove_wall(i, j)
                else:
                    maze.set_wall(i, j)

        return maze

    @staticmethod
    def complete_maze(Width, Height):
        maze = Maze(Width, Height)

        for i in range(Width):
            for j in range(Height):
                maze.board[i][j] = WALL

        return maze


    def create_maze(x, y):
       Maze.set_path(x, y)
       all_directions = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]]
       random.shuffle(all_directions)

       while len(all_directions) > 0:
           direction_to_try = all_directions.pop()
           node_x = x + (direction_to_try[0] * 2)
           node_y = y + (direction_to_try[1] * 2)

           if Maze.is_wall(node_x, node_y):
               link_cell_x = x + direction_to_try[0]
               link_cell_y = y + direction_to_try[1]
               self.set_path(link_cell_x, link_cell_y)
               self.create_maze(node_x, node_y)
       return
```

Comment: "create_maze" is missing "self" parameter.

Comment: If I do that then if I try calling it from outside the class it says that it misses the argument 'y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the definition for set_path:

`def set_path(self, x, y):`

This expects three parameters. When you call it with `Maze.set_path(x,y)`, you're only giving it two: `x` and `y`. Python expects three and in the order `self`, then `x`, then `y`. Python is interpreting the `x` you give to be `self`, then the `y` to be `x` and then gives an error that `y` isn't given. But what is actually missing is `self`!

To fix this, you need to change this call to `self.set_path(x, y)` (which is a shortcut for `Maze.set_path(self, x, y)`). You'll also need to pass `self` to `create_maze` as well by changing its definition to `def create_maze(self, x, y)`. And finally, change the way you call `create_maze()` to something like

`maze = Maze(NoOfRows, NoOfCols).create_maze(NoOfRows, NoOfColumns)`

As an aside, it seems you never use `self.Width` or `self.Height`. You should either remove them from `__init__` and just take the `x` and `y` passed in `create_maze()`, or change `create_maze()` to use `self.Width` and `self.Height` instead of taking `x` and `y` as parameters.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get a different error for self path when I pass 50 and 50 for x and y , line 35, in set_path
    self.board[y][x] = False
IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 50

Comment: That's because your board is x by y in size, meaning its indices range from (0 to x-1) by (0 to y-1). Accessing board[x][y] is thus out of bounds. You'll need to start from a different position, and include some checks in your functions to avoid going out of bounds.